# Embed Sequence API in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, word-embeddings

My current tensorflow version is 2.1 and I'm using low level(core) tensorflow api's.
Please provide a substitute of **"tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence"**.

I have explored a lot, but could not find any relevant api.

Also tf2.3 API **"tf.keras.layers.Embedding"** can be used for sequential model only and not with core API's.

Comment: Same problem!, They just know to break things without any migration guide!